# Stack Overflow when debugging application in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, build-process, stack-overflow

I'm getting this every time I attempt to debug my app in the simulator:

```
[Session started at 2010-05-11 16:16:52 -0500.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1467) (Wed Apr 21 06:57:21 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 51573.
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Cannot call into the loader at present, it is locked.)
```

I've looked around and found a few similar cases, but they all seem to be related to a missing file and an extra necessary build phase. I'm getting no notification of a missing file here so I'm not sure where to start to fix this and get the app running again.

Thanks for any insight!

**EDIT:**
I have some frameworks showing up in red (and apparently not on my system since I've installed a new SDK version). I'm assuming this is the problem, but I can't seem to find UIKit.framework or CoreGraphics.framework anywhere on my system now.

**Edit 2:**
Went through and found all of the associated frameworks in other locations and changed the framework locations in the project. They're no longer red in Groups & Files but the original problem still persists.

Comment: I have some frameworks showing up in red (and apparently not on my system since I've installed a new SDK version). I'm assuming this is the problem, but I can't seem to find UIKit.framework or CoreGraphics.framework anywhere on my system now.

Comment: Went through and found all of the associated frameworks in other locations and changed the framework locations in the project. They're no longer red in Groups & Files but the original problem still persists.

Comment: Are you able to run the application without debug or on a device?

Comment: It wasn't working on the device either but I've figured out the problem: I had to put in a fix to implement UITableViewCellContentView in a previous SDK version because of crashes that occurred. This new version apparently fixed that issue so I simply had to take out the extra implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the problem: I had to put in a fix to implement `UITableViewCellContentView` in a previous SDK version because of crashes that occurred. This new version apparently fixed that issue so I simply had to take out the extra implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably referencing a deallocated object. [Turn on NSZombie](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone) to get better details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this didn't change anything. Still getting the same exact error and NSZombie isn't showing any additional details. I was hoping it'd be that simple but apparently it isn't.